# How do I pin a location on laravel backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I want to pin a location when user enter his address information in laravel backpack?

this is Address field in controller

```
                'name'  => 'address-input', 
                'type'  => 'customGoogleMaps', 
                'label' => "Google Maps",
                'hint'  => 'Help text',
                 'attributes' => [
             'class' => 'form-control map-input', 
      ],
  'view_namespace' => 'custom-google-maps-field-for-backpack::fields',
```

This is customGoogleMaps field (customGoogleMaps.blade.php)

```
<div @include('crud::inc.field_wrapper_attributes')>
    <label>{!! $field['label'] !!}</label>
    <input type="text" id="{{ $field['name'] }}" name="{{ $field['name'] }}"

        value="{{ old($field['name']) ? old($field['name']) : (isset($field['value']) ? $field['value'] : (isset($field['default']) ? $field['default'] : '' )) }}"
        @include('crud::inc.field_attributes')>

    <input type="hidden" name="address_latitude" id="address-latitude" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="address_longitude" id="address-longitude" value="0" />

    <div id="address-map-container" style="width:100%;height:400px; ">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%" id="address-map"></div>
    </div>

    {{-- HINT --}}
    @if (isset($field['hint']))
    <p class="help-block">{!! $field['hint'] !!}</p>
    @endif
</div>

@if ($crud->checkIfFieldIsFirstOfItsType($field, $fields))
{{-- FIELD EXTRA CSS  --}}
{{-- push things in the after_styles section --}}

@push('crud_fields_styles')
<!-- no styles -->
@endpush

{{-- FIELD EXTRA JS --}}
{{-- push things in the after_scripts section --}}

@push('crud_fields_scripts')
<!-- no scripts -->
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{ env('GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY') }}&libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {

            $('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
                if (keyCode === 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            const locationInputs = document.getElementsByClassName("map-input");

            const autocompletes = [];
            const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            for (let i = 0; i < locationInputs.length; i++) {

                const input = locationInputs[i];
                const fieldKey = input.id.replace("-input", "");
                const isEdit = document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-latitude").value != '' && document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-longitude").value != '';

                const latitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-latitude").value) || -33.8688;
                const longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById(fieldKey + "-longitude").value) || 151.2195;

                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(fieldKey + '-map'), {
                    center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
                    zoom: 13
                });
                const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
                });

                marker.setVisible(isEdit);

                const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                autocomplete.key = fieldKey;
                autocompletes.push({input: input, map: map, marker: marker, autocomplete: autocomplete});
            }

            for (let i = 0; i < autocompletes.length; i++) {
                const input = autocompletes[i].input;
                const autocomplete = autocompletes[i].autocomplete;
                const map = autocompletes[i].map;
                const marker = autocompletes[i].marker;

                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                    geocoder.geocode({'placeId': place.place_id}, function (results, status) {
                        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                            const lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                            setLocationCoordinates(autocomplete.key, lat, lng);
                        }
                    });

                    if (!place.geometry) {
                        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                        input.value = "";
                        return;
                    }

                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(17);
                    }
                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                    marker.setVisible(true);

                });
            }
        }

        function setLocationCoordinates(key, lat, lng) {
            const latitudeField = document.getElementById(key + "-" + "latitude");
            const longitudeField = document.getElementById(key + "-" + "longitude");
            latitudeField.value = lat;
            longitudeField.value = lng;
        }
    </script>
@endpush
@endif
```

It display the following Error:

InvalidArgumentException View [inc.field_wrapper_attributes] not found. (View:
C:\xampp\htdocs\CRM\vendor\abr4xas\gmaps-input-backpack\src\resources\views\fields\customGoogleMaps.blade.php)